# Ruby mix 3 uneven arrays balanced regarding to the array's lengths

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm searching for a Ruby method or a general algorithm to sort 3 arrays into a new one. The criteria is that these 3 arrays have different lengths and that the result should reflect that regarding to the position of each of the elements in the new array.

Lets say I have these 3 arrays:

```
array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
array2 = ['a','b','c']
array3 = ['x','y']
```

The end result should the look something like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[ 'a',   'b',   'c']
[    'x',    'y']
```

As you can see, the sorting should not be entirely random, each element should be placed regarding to the number of elements its original array has.

What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explan how you got this result form those arrays?

Comment: It is just an example I hardcoded. The person who downvoted me could at least say why he did it.

Comment: Is there a rule or are you merging the three arrays randomly?

Comment: It's not clear how you come from your input to your output. Unless you can describe the necessary steps in natural language, it is very hard to help you as we don't know what you want to achieve. Incidentally, once you have written down what you want to achieve exactly, you probably have already found your algorithm...

Comment: @LinusAn - It is impossible for us to guess the logic behind it. For me it looks like randomly summed array.

Comment: That's what I tried to express with 'balanced'. The sorting should not be entirely random, the position of each element should be placed regarding to the number of elements its original array has.

Comment: What is the logic when comparing char with a Fixnum ?

Comment: @Santosh not the numbers itself but the length of the arrays should be compared.

Comment: 'x' is missing in the result

Comment: Still doesnt make sense. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your requirements, but here's my attempt:

1. Calculate each element's *relative* position, i.e. 1st element = position 0, middle element = position 0.5, last element = position 1
2. Merge all element / position pairs in a single array
3. Sort the array by the calculated position
4. Extract the elements / remove the position

Example implementation:

```
array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
array3 = ['x', 'y']

def pos(array)
  array.map.with_index { |e, i| [e, i / (array.size - 1.0)] }
end

result = pos(array1) + pos(array2) + pos(array3)
#=> [[0, 0.0], [1, 0.1111111111111111], [2, 0.2222222222222222], [3, 0.3333333333333333], [4, 0.4444444444444444], [5, 0.5555555555555556], [6, 0.6666666666666666], [7, 0.7777777777777778], [8, 0.8888888888888888], [9, 1.0], ["a", 0.0], ["b", 0.5], ["c", 1.0], ["x", 0.0], ["y", 1.0]]

result.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first)
#=> [0, "a", "x", 1, 2, 3, 4, "b", 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "c", "y"]
```

You can change the order by tweaking the calculation, e.g. `(i + 1) / (array.size + 1.0)` gives:

```
#=> [0, 1, "a", 2, "x", 3, 4, "b", 5, 6, "y", 7, "c", 8, 9]
```

Comment: @LinusAn I've added another calculation to distribute the elements differently

Comment: thanks again for your additional help